# Xrm.Sdk Linq with Joins and dynamic where

Tags: c#, linq, dynamics-crm, xrm

After a bunch of time getting my query syntactically correct it looks like the the sdk has some limitations.. i also tried a sub query with facility but it returned a IQuery (i or something). Is there a way to achieve a dynamic where clause in a Linq Xrm Query

the exception thrown

> System.NotSupportedException: The method 'Where' cannot follow the method 'Select' or is not supported. Try writing the query in terms of supported methods or call the 'AsEnumerable' or 'ToList' m
>   ethod before calling unsupported methods.

```cs
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.New<GetAllResult>(false);

if (query?.ObservationOnStart != null && query?.ObservationOnEnd != null)
{
    predicate.And(result =>
        result.ObservationEntity.esor_ObservationOn >= query.ObservationOnStart &&
        result.ObservationEntity.esor_ObservationOn <= query.ObservationOnEnd);
}


var queryable = from observationEntity in _ctx.esor_ObservationSet
        join facilityEntity in _ctx.core_FacilitySet
            on observationEntity.esor_Facility.Id equals facilityEntity.Id
        orderby observationEntity.esor_ObservationOn
        select new GetAllResult {ObservationEntity = observationEntity, FacilityEntity = facilityEntity}
    ;


// THIS throws exception
 queryable.Where(predicate).ToList();
```

I have also tried checking the a varable and used and OR but it also throws an exception

```
where completedById.Equals(null) || observationEntity.esor_CompletedBy.Id.Equals(completedById)
```

> System.NotSupportedException: Invalid 'where' condition. An entity member is invoking an invalid property or method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first code snippet, you first call:

```
select new GetAllResult
```

and then

```
queryable.Where(predicate)
```

which doesn't work. because - as you've find out - you can't call `where` after calling `select`.

Then, in your second code snippet, you call:

```
where completedById.Equals(null)
```

Which doesn't work because the left hand side of the where clause has to be an entity attribute name, while `completedById` is apparently a variable you've delcared somewhere.

CRM Dynamics's Linq queries must be kept pretty simple, and if you insist on using Linq (and not, say, `QueryExpression`), do as follows:

```
// ... build you queryable, and then:

// 1. first, call ToList()
var records = queryable.ToList();

// 2. then, filter it with Where()
if (query?.ObservationOnStart != null && query?.ObservationOnEnd != null)
{
    records = records.Where(r =>
        r.ObservationEntity.esor_ObservationOn >= query.ObservationOnStart &&
        r.ObservationEntity.esor_ObservationOn <= query.ObservationOnEnd
    ).ToList();
}
```

Comment: i now realize i have to use a query expression.. i cant do much with the linq

Comment: Remember you can use `FetchExpression` as well. Also, If you consider this question answered, please mark it as accepted.